# Is it good idea to use macro to get rid of dependant template keyword?

Tags: c++, templates

today I found out that if I want to call templated method of a templated class I have to use `template keyword` after `.` or `->`. Like this:

```
template <class T>
class Foo 
{
    public:
    template <class I>
    void templatedMethod() {};
};

template<typename T, typename I>
void oops() {
    Foo<T>().template templatedMethod<I>(); // error without template kw
}

int main()
{
    oops<double, int>();
}
```

My problem is that this templatedMethod is part of my public api and I don't want the users to type the `template` since it is not that regular and it might discourage potential users.

My question is:
is it good idea to rename `templatedMethod` to something like `_templatedMethod` and then in the same header file provide `macro` `#define templatedMethod template _templatedMethod?`

User is then able to normally call it:

```
Foo<T> f;
f.templatedMethod<I>();
```

What could go wrong? How is this problem usually solved?
Thank you.

Comment: `_templatedMethod` -- You shouldn't create names with leading underscores.  Names with leading underscores are reserved for the compiler's implementation.

Comment: You don't need `template` there anyways? https://godbolt.org/z/fkG2is

Comment: [Cannot duplicate](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/03817c515c0dfd8a).  More than likely, your code is more complicated than what you posted -- in which scenario were you required to use `template`?  Better yet, take the code from either link that was posted in the comments, add to it,  duplicate your issue, and post that code, not just a snippet.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie You are right. I will edit the snippet once i manage to find some minimal example. The case in my code is a bit too complicated.

Comment: *Food for thought as you clarify your question:* The setup of your question matches that of [`std::vector::emplace_back()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/emplace_back), and yet `emplace_back()` is usually called without needing the `template` keyword.

Comment: @vens -- Well, maybe you've answered your own question.  If the user of your code has put themselves in a place where they must use `template`, wouldn't it be their "fault"?  If the user wants to write complex code, then it's up to them to figure out to use `template`.  As you can see, normal usage doesn't require `template` to be used.  This is no different than what many C++ programmers encounter when writing non-trivial code, and must call a template function.  They figure out through research that `template` has to be used, and they're satisfied with that solution.

Comment: `template` is needed when the you don't know the contents of `Foo<T>`, as in [this example](https://godbolt.org/z/K3EeCL). In `oops`, the nature of `templatedMethod` is unknown. `templatedMethod<int()>(x)` could be specializing and calling a template function, or it could be two comparisons. `template` declares you meant the first, while the second is the default. I agree with @PaulMcKenzie, this is "just a C++ thing" your user should know about and deal with, instead of you doing dark magic. In particular, your user now cannot name anything else `templatedFunction`, which is *very* broken.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie thats very good thought. I will leave it with the template kw. Thank you.

Comment: @HTNW I didn't realize that templatedFunction cannot be used after that... Thanks. BTW I edited your example little bit to provide snippet for my answer. Hope you dont mind :)

Comment: @JaMiT I am actually doing something very very similar to emplace_back(). The only difference is that I cannot "deduce" the template argument from class template argument as std::vector::emplace_back() can.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie it's my understanding that a single leading underscore is acceptable, as long as the character that follows it is lower-case.